# Double bluetooth icons

Tags: 13.04, laptop, bluetooth, taskbar

My taskbar shows double bluetooth icons when my bluetooth is activated:

[image: Double Bluetooth icons]

When I click the rightmost I get to see this menu:

[image]

And this is the menu of the icon to the left:

[image]

The 'about' window:

[image]

How do I merge the icons, or remove them?

Comment: Since when do you experience this problem? Did your upgrade your Ubuntu version or something? Would be interesing how this happened. Should be relatively easy to solve, though.

Comment: It happened since I have been messing with my graphics drivers, xorg and xubuntu-desktop

Comment: The bug is already reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta/+bug/1168813
It seems like blueman is the ubuntu applet. I recommend you try uninstalling bluetooth-applet (if it is installed). Try "sudo apt-get purge bluetooth-applet" in terminal.

Comment: the package bluetooth-applet isn't installed on my machine.

Comment: Try clicking **About** on the left one. Edit your answer to include a screenshot.

Comment: In my 13.04 installation, I don't have `blueman` installed. Uninstall it, and try installing `indicator-bluetooth` if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, Blueman needs to be uninstalled:

```
pkill blueman
sudo apt-get purge blueman
```

The icons are now gone. To access the bluetooth settings now, you need to go to your system settings.

Comment: Is there no solution that will only give the newest version of the bluetooth menu? It seems like blueman is installed in two different versions. Maybe installing blueman again could work? (unfortunately I can't test it now)

Comment: I've just tested it and it resulted in the same double-icon problem.